# Visual Studio 2019. Error MSB8020

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Не могу начать писать плагины SAMPFUNCS. 
Установил Visual Studio, распаковал проект SFPlugin и открыл. Вот ошибка, ни как не могу понять с чем связана ошибка и как его исправить.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(379,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (Platform Toolset = 'v110_xp') cannot be found. To build using the v110_xp build tools, please install Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".
1>Сборка проекта "SFPlugin.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
```

Ссылка на SFPlugin https://blast.hk/attachments/22939/

Я еще заметил что в название проекта написано Visual Studio 2012, хотя у меня установлен 2019. Вот скрин [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажать на правую кнопку мыши по проекту выходит вот это.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там же написано, нажмите правой кнопкой по проекту и выберите вашу целевую систему.   Цитата из ошибки "right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution""

Comment: @B1aZe да в том то и дело что у меня русская версия и я не знаю какая это кнопка. Гугл переводчик не помогает, я понажимал почти все кнопки. Ничего не помогло. Я отредактировал, теперь вы можете посмотреть как выглядит список если нажать правую кнопку мыши на проект.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого случая я предлагаю вам следовать этим двум инструкциям, также перед запуском убедитесь что вы запускаете именно ту версию которую вы установили, и перед установкой нового, рекомендую удалить полностью старую версию и все другие.

1. Установите версисию 2017 по ссылке и попробуйте снова .

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes

2. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на свой проект, перейдите в Свойства. Под Свойствами конфигурации перейдите к Общему. Измените ваш набор инструментов платформы на один из доступных.

Comment: Спасибо, я так долго не мог это сделать!

Comment: Удалять 19 студию, для того чтобы указать целевую систему в свойствах, было лишним. 2 пункт нужно было сделать и проект бы работал.

Comment: @B1aZe 2 пункт, пересобрать ? Ошибка выходило именно тогда, когда я пытался пересобрать. Я так долго искал решение, и думаю для плагина SAMPFUNCS подойдет и 17 версия. Если что я просто обновлю. Спасибо что откликнулись на мой вопрос. :)

Comment: @Mukhtar Amirkhanov, указать в свойствах проекта целевую платформу, а потом пересобрать

Comment: @B1aZe Ааа... Я только понял. Еще раз спасибо :)))